# Error to view all in data table in php

Tags: php, arrays

When i run it. i only see 1 records of customer and it says that the error is in " WHILE($cus = mysql_fetch_array($cus)){" Line.. anyone knows how to solve it? ..tnx

```
<table id="datatables" class="display">

    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FullName</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Barangay</th>
            <th>CompleteAddress</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <?php $cus = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer") or die(mysql_error()); ?>

        <?php
        WHILE ($cus = mysql_fetch_array($cus)) {

            $id = $cus['cus_id'];
            $email = $cus['email'];
            $control = $cus['cus_id'];
            $user = $cus['username'];
            $pass = $cus['password'];
            $brgy = $cus['barangay'];
            $comadd = $cus['com_address'];
            $age = $cus['age'];
            $gend = $cus['gender'];

            $fname = $cus['firstname'] . "&nbsp;" . $cus['middlename'] . "&nbsp;" . $cus['lastname'];
            ?>

            <tr class="gradeA del<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <td><?php echo $control; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $age; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $gend; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $brgy; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $comadd; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pass; ?></td>

            </tr>

            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: i think we need to see a little more of the surrounding code to help you.

Comment: Watch out for XSS! Please use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when outputting to HTML.

Comment: Vote to close because of error message tease.

Comment: @MikeB What do you mean by "error message tease"? I don't see an error message at all, so Rain: what is the error you get?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel He says he got an error message but failed to include it in his question: `says that the error is in " WHILE($cus = mysql_fetch_array($cus)){" Line..`

Comment: some of my code is missing the post is not complete.. i got error in the line <?php while($cus = mysql_fetch_array($cus)) { .... and only 1  customer data viewed in the data table.

Comment: Then post all your code. And you still don't say what the error is you get.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\FINAL_THESIS\admin\member_list.php on line 95

and the line 95 is the <? WHILE($cus = mysql_fetch_array($cus)){

Comment: change `WHILE ($cus = mysql_fetch_array($cus)) {` to `WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_array($cus)) {` and then update everything in the while to use `$row['field']`.  you cant use `$cus` as your result set and as the row info.

Comment: So you omitted the error because you knew it was a massively duplicated question on this site.. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_fetch_array%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+resource+is%3Aquestion. Close please.

Comment: tnx guys.... i solve it.... i use the WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_array($cus)) {
and make the $row['field']
sorry for the bother...

Comment: @RainAiros The thing you should take away from this question is that developers respond 1000% better to error messages than walls of text trying to describe the problem or copy/paste of scripts. Developers don't comb code looking for problems unless its a last resort. They rely on error messages to guide them. With that error message a good developer could have deduced the problem in your code without even seeing it.

Comment: @RainAiros - see my answer down below... I re-stated my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use $cus as the result set for the query and the row information.  one of these variables needs to be something different.  in my comment above, I suggested turning one into row but it's a lot easier to just change the name of the result set, so that is what I did in the code below.

I assume you have the correct connection set up before your pasted code starts, too.

```
<table id="datatables" class="display">

    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FullName</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Barangay</th>
            <th>CompleteAddress</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <?php 

        // this used to be $cus but I renamed it... 
        $customer_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer") or die(mysql_error());  

        //  here was the issue... you were using $cus twice.  
        WHILE ($cus = mysql_fetch_array($customer_results)) 
        { 
            $id = $cus['cus_id'];
            $email = $cus['email'];
            $control = $cus['cus_id'];
            $user = $cus['username'];
            $pass = $cus['password'];
            $brgy = $cus['barangay'];
            $comadd = $cus['com_address'];
            $age = $cus['age'];
            $gend = $cus['gender'];

            $fname = $cus['firstname'] . "&nbsp;" . $cus['middlename'] . "&nbsp;" . $cus['lastname'];
            ?>

            <tr class="gradeA del<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <td><?php echo $control; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $age; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $gend; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $brgy; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $comadd; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pass; ?></td>

            </tr>

            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Keep in mind, `mysql` functions are old and will be removed from PHP.  You should not waste your time learning them.  Instead use PDO or MYSQLI.  Personally, I think PDO is easier.  If you decide to switch over to one of those two new DB classes, be sure to parameterize your queries and bind values to help prevent SQL injection.

Comment: ok2...tnx.. i'm kinda new in php and learning more and more... i love coding :) tnx for it.

Answer (score 1):

Please close your missing while loop curly braces.

Complete code:-

```
    <?php 
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($cus)) {
            $id = $rows['cus_id'];
            $email = $rows['email'];
            $control = $rows['cus_id'];
            $user = $rows['username'];
            $pass = $rows['password'];
            $brgy = $rows['barangay'];
            $comadd = $rows['com_address'];
            $age = $rows['age'];
            $gend = $rows['gender'];
            $fname = $rows['firstname'] . "&nbsp;" . $rows['middlename']. "&nbsp;" . $rows['lastname'];
            ?>

            <tr class="gradeA del<?php echo $id;?>">
                    <td><?php echo $control; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $age; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $gend; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $brgy; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $comadd; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pass; ?></td>

            </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I think the error would be different if that was the issue... it would be incorrect index for `$cus['cus_id'];` or something.  that might be an issue, too... but i don't think that will solve it.

Comment: Nope this doesn't matter. `mysql_fetch_array` will grab both types and hence that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing statement for your `while` loop. Add this to the bottom

```
<?php } ?>
```

Second issue

```
while($cus = mysql_fetch_array($cus)) {  // You are overwriting the recordset
```

Change the variable name there

```
while($cusTemp = mysql_fetch_array($cus)) {  // or any other name convenient
```

Comment: oh, no, look!  he's using `$cus` as his result set and as the row variable, too.  I think we need to see more of the surrounding code to know what the real issue is....

Comment: The while statement has to close somewhere, otherwise they will always get the syntax error they are getting

Comment: After that is resolved then yes that `$cus` has to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You get from `$cus`, and assign it to `$cus` as well. This means you will see 1 record, and afterwards it fails on the next fetch since you changed the context:

```
while($cusdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($cus)){
```

Would be better :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this code:

```
<?php while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($cus)) !== false) { ?>
    <tr>
        <tr class="gradeA del<?php echo $row['cus_id'];?>">
        <td><?php echo $row['cus_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['firstname'] . "&nbsp;" . $row['middlename']. "&nbsp;" . $row['lastname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['barangay']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['com_address']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

The code is clean, condition is properly checked against `FALSE` and no need for useless lines of code...